# Sqlite Database Access : No such table (Within Django no models)

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a django & docker server running on my computer and I have created a database with code from outside this server. I am trying to access this database ('test.sqlite3') within the server.

I made sure the path was the correct one and that the file name was correct as well. When I open the database with DB Browser, I can see the tables and all my data. But I still get the following error text:

OperationalError no such table: NAMEOFTABLE

When I use the exact same code from another python IDE (spyder) it works fine. I'm guessing there's something weird going on with django?

Here is some of the code:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("../test.sqlite3")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT firstName, lastName FROM RESOURCES")
conn.close()
```

(Yes, I have also tried using the absolute path and I get the same error.)

Also to be noted: I get this same error when I try to create the database file & table from within the django code (the path should then be the same but it still get the error in this case).

Update: it seems I have a problem with my path because I can't even open a text file with python and it's absolute path. So if anyone has any idea why that'd be great.

```
    try:
        f = open("/Users/XXXXX/OneDrive/XXXXX/XXXX/Autres/argon-dashboard-django/toto.txt")
        # Do something with the file
    except IOError:
        q="File not accessible"
    finally:
        f.close()
```

always return the following error 'f referenced before assignment' and q = "File not accesible" so that means I can't even find the text file.

Comment: Could you show us the file hierachy... Is there a particular reason you're connecting to the database that way in django? i.e. are you using multuiples, as you can configure that in settings.

Comment: I'm not using models from django so I figured I'd use sqlite since I also know the language. I have the code in my funtions.py file inside an "app" folder. The sqlite3 file is at the same level as the "app" folder. Here's the basic file hierarchy:
app
     funtions.py
     ...
test2.sqlite3

Comment: I would perhaps retag the qeustion and skip the django tag if this unrelated. On a side note, the ORM in Django is one of the fundamental points of using DJango. Sounds like you could have just used Flask if your want to manage the DB stuff ya self. But either the answer is the path is wrong. Try ```base_dir = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent``` and appending the db file name. or logging out that path and working back from there to discover where you're looking in relation to the file.

Comment: Sorry about the tag, but I started usign django because at first there was no need for a database (and I've never done web dev before) and someone recommended this to me. And since it works outside of VSCode and Django I thought the problem might come from there. I'll try that.

Comment: Yeah, I get it. Although if you didn't need the models, i really wouldn't bother with django. Try Flask.. may be more what you're looking for and if it's early days then rewriting the urls in to Flask, probably wont be much effort. Or go the other-way embrace the tool that you've chosen and use it to it's potential and you can avoid this type pf issues as Django, out of the box creates an sqlite db and django Models are easy enough to implement.  Do the tuts on the django my first app. It'll take you about the time it's taken you to debug this issue.

Comment: Thanks. Your previous suggestion didn't work either. I used a template in django to get started (I was kinda just thrown into this as you can see) and I tried using the models and did follow a tutorial but the migrate and makemigrations never did anything so I gave up on that as well. And the code works in a basic IDE so idk

Comment: Hmm, if the migrations didn't work, that would indicate a problem. go back over the https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial01/ and try again. You either missed a step, like adding the app name to your INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py (usually why migrate or makemigrations) has no affect.

Comment: I had spent about 2 days on trying to figure that out and that was ok, i had created the models, explicitly wrote makemigrations app, declared the models in admin.py which I why in the end I gave up (I am getting my data using an API so I figured I could do without). but now I actually need a database to store manual inserted data on top of requested data.

Comment: You declared the models in `admin.py` unless you misspoke that would be the main reason. That tutorial takes 1hr tops. needless to say you don't create models in admin.py models are created in models.py, admin is for the `/admin` endpoint for creating instances or editing them via the browser. Anywayof you follow that link and it stil doesn't work, fair enough. But it sound slike you skimmed it and got it badly wrong. try again.

Comment: But shouldn't migrations still have worked? I tried every possible combination of what I stated above so I did try to migrate without anything in the admin file and the models created in models.py.

And the real problem still lies in why a normal IDE can make the code work without problem.

Comment: `python manage.py migrate` should have worked to start, `python manage.py makemigrations` should have then worked to created any new models you'd defined in `models.py` in you app, assuming you'd add you're app as described above to settings and that you'd rum `python manage.py startapp my_app` 1st. It's all in the tutorial, so I"m out hope that helps

Comment: Yeah I did all that to no actual effect so I'm really lost lol. The template might be doing something here.
And if I'm back with the current problem, the code isn't creating a new database anywhere on my computer (which would happen if the path was wrong) so it's really weird xD

Comment: Update: it seems I have a problem with my path because I can't even open a text file with python and it's absolute path. So if anyone has any idea why that'd be great. (Also written in the post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this problem, I used two things:

- I moved the sqlite3 file within the app folder and used '/app/db.sqlite3' as the path
- Added ; at the ends of my SQL requests

```
c.execute("SELECT firstName, lastName FROM RESOURCES;")
```

Not sure which one solved the problem but everything works for me now.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue, possibly something about leaving Django Model metadata files outside of the image. I needed to synchronize the model with the DB using a run-syncdb

```
RUN ["python", "manage.py", "migrate"]
RUN ["python", "manage.py", "migrate", "--run-syncdb"]
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```